# Take lasts characters from every line of a file

Tags: bash

I am learning bash and I have a file with 500000 lines, each of them has this pattern:

**NNNNNNNN    NNNNNN C**

N = number  |  C = char A-Z  |  First space is a tab, second is a regular space.

I want to create a file with the last part, starting at the second column of numbers (**NNNNNN C**) using a bash script. I was able to do it with:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 500000 ]
do
    echo $i
    sed $i"q;d" $1 | tail -c 9 >> file
    ((i++))
done
```

But it takes ages because it writes each line into the file, one by one. How can I do this faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`cut`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/), which uses tabs as a delimiter by default.

To read `infile` and put fields (`-f`) 2 onwards (`2-`) into `file`:

```
cut -f2- infile > file
```

Comment: Great and simple. I have read the man page and I was able to do it with `cut -c 10-17 $1 > $2` too, and using parameters. Thank you!

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. Often the simplest utilities are the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read` to split each line into words, and then print the ones you want:

```
while read a b c; do
  echo "$b $c"
done < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: That works perfect, I think I will use it in another type of file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

yes, that would take a while. And while you DIY spirit is to be commended with using bash, this sort of task is usually taken care of with the unix tool that was designed for such tasks.

Try this

```
 sed 's/^.*<T>//' file > outFile
```

where `<T>` is either  '\t' or the literal tab char, depending on your version of sed.

This deletes everything up to the first tab on each line in your file and then prints what is left into outFile.

IHTH.

Comment: It will be very useful for other files, using RegEx. Thank you!